# Check if duplicate exists and then append a unique digit to line?

Tags: python, linux, string, file

INPUT.TXT looks like this -

```
pr-ec2_1034
pr-ec2_1023
pr-ec2_1099
```

I want to write a python script which will read this file & add +1 to the line with highest number and then print that line.

Desired output -

```
pr-ec2_1100
```

Right now I am able to add +1 to all lines like -

```
def increment_digits(string):
    return ''.join([x if not x.isdigit() else str((int(x) + 1) % 10) for x in string])

with open('INPUT.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
print(increment_digits(data))
```

Output-

```
pr-ec3_2145
pr-ec3_2134
pr-ec3_2134
```

but this is not what I want. I want to find the line the with largest ending number in input.txt and add +1 to only to that one line after (last underscore)

**pr-ec2_1100** is what I want

Comment: What have you tried? Where else have you looked for suggestions? What problems have you run into? What code have you written so far? What does that code do/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  numbers = [int(l.split('_')[1]) for l in lines]
  _max = max(numbers)
  result = _max + 1
  print('result: pr-ec2_{}'.format(result))
```

output

```
pr-ec2_1100
```